# role attribute of h:panelGrid

Tags: jsf

I'm using exaples from the official Java EE tutorial In which contains the follow:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2"
    headerClass="list-header"
    styleClass="list-background"
    rowClasses="list-row-even, list-row-odd"
    summary="#{bundle.CustomerInfo}"
    title="#{bundle.Checkout}"
    role="presentation">
```

But compiler says that attribute role is not defined for `h:panelGrid` component. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That attribute was introduced in JSF 2.2. As evidence, the `role` attribute is mentioned in [JSF 2.2 `<h:panelGrid>` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/panelGrid.html), but not in [JSF 2.1 `<h:panelGrid>` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/panelGrid.html).

Your question history confirms that you're using JSF 2.2 on GlassFish 4.0, so this compiler warning is actually wrong. This is not exactly a JSF problem, but an IDE problem. The IDE is somehow thinking that you're not using JSF 2.2, but JSF 2.1 or older. I.e. your toolset is working against you. You didn't mention which IDE you're using, so it's not possible to post the right answer.

If the project runs fine and the JSF page produces the right HTML output (i.e. the `role` attribute actually ends up in generated HTML `<table>` element as you can see by rightclick, *View Source* in webbrowser), then everything is well and it's just the IDE who's pretending to be smarter than it actually is.

I'd start peeking around in IDE project's properties to check if the JSF versions are all right. The JSF facet in project's properties must be set to version 2.2, not lower. The `faces-config.xml` must be declared conform JSF 2.2, not lower.